# How to find duplicate letter in array in C

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

I am making a program which requires the user to input an argument (argv[1]) where the argument is every letter of the alphabet rearranged however the user likes it. Examples of valid input is "YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO" and "JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ". Examples of invalid input would then be "VCHPRZGJVTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI" and "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUYYYYY" since there are duplicates of 'V' and 'Y' in the respective examples.

What I know so far is, that you can loop through the whole argument like the following

```
for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); j < n; j++)
{
   //Place something in here...
}
```

However, I do not quite know if this would be the right way to go when looking for duplicates? Furthermore, I want the answer to be as simple as possible, right know time and cpu usage is not a priority, so "the best" algorithm is not necessarily the one I am looking for.

Comment: You will eventually need to check every single character of the input, so looping through them all is a good start.

Comment: How would you do it if you were handed a piece of paper with said character sequence written down, and all you had was another piece of paper and a pencil? Answer that, and you'll have one (of several) possible algorithms.

Comment: The simplest option in my opinion is the option of using switch(arg[i]) { case 'A': int x++; break; and so on alphabetically.

Comment: n = strlen(argv[1] not work. n=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that all your letters are capital letters you can use a hash table to make this algorithm work in `O(n)` time complexity.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int arr[50]={};

    for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); j < n; j++)
    {
        arr[argv[1][j]-'A']++;
    }

    printf("duplicate letters: ");
    for(int i=0;i<'Z'-'A'+1;i++){
        if(arr[i]>=2)printf("%c ",i+'A');
    }
}
```

here we make an array `arr` initialized to zeros. this array will keep count of the occurrences of every letter.
and then we look for letters that appeared 2 or more times those are the duplicated letters.
Also using that same array you can check if all the letters occured at least once to check if it is a permutation

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    char * input = "ABCC";
    /*
     *For any character, its value must be locate in 0 ~ 255, so we just
     *need to check counter of corresponding index whether greater than zero. 
     */
    size_t ascii[256] = {0, };
    char * cursor = input;
    char c = '\0';
    while((c=*cursor++))
    {
        if(ascii[c] == 0)
            ++ascii[c];
        else
        {
            printf("Find %c has existed.\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add a bit of explanation. please review [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the type of code that you are looking for, but here's what I did. It looks for the duplicates in the given set of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 50

int main() {
   char stringArg[max];
     int dupliCount = 0;
      
      printf("Enter A string: ");
          scanf("%s",stringArg);
               system("cls");

        int length = strlen(stringArg);
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<length; j++){
        if(stringArg[i] == stringArg[j]){
            dupliCount +=1;
        }
    }
}
if(dupliCount > 0)
      printf("Invalid Input");
printf("Valid Input");    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet is used to count the duplicate letters in the array.
If you want to remove the letters, Also this code snippet is helpful .Set null when the same characters are in the same letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int count=0;
int array[]={'e','d','w','f','b','e'};
for(int i=0;i<array.Lenth;i++)
{
for(int j=1;j<array.Length;j++)
{
if(array[i]==array[j])
{
count++;
}
}
}
printf("The dublicate letter count is : %d",count);
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. Please post code that compiles, ideally something free of typos that you have actually tested. There is no such thing as `array.Length`, are you confusing this for some other programming language?

Comment: Also please note that a pure linear search like this is the slowest possible algorithm.